# how to add View to XML layout android

Tags: android, view, android-animation

I have a XML layout that contain all my buttons and images and i want a moving cloud on the top of my layout. so i created a view and made my cloud move, however i couldnt link the view with layout. here is my view code

```
public class CloudView extends View {

Bitmap cloud;
int ChangingX;


public CloudView(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    cloud = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cloud);
    ChangingX = 50;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(cloud, ChangingX , 50, null);
    if (ChangingX < canvas.getWidth())
        ChangingX += 2;
    else
        ChangingX = 50;
    invalidate();
}

}
```

and here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CloudView myView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myView = new CloudView(this);
    setContentView(myView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Im new at animation in android can u explain in details how i can link a View with layout.
and if it wont work what other classes besides View that i can use.

Thanks for your time and consideration. and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Use layout inflater to add new view.

Comment: can you please show in code how to use inflater, i have never used it before

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Android Developer Link might me useful for you.

[Define Custom Attributes](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

How to define attribute :

To define custom attributes, add  resources to your project. It's customary to put these resources into a `res/values/attrs.xml` file. Here's an example of an `attrs.xml` file:

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

How to use in `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews">
 <com.example.customviews.charting.PieChart
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Read for more details do follow.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.activity_my_vault, null,false);
        this.addContentView(viewToLoad);
```

Comment: i need to add this on MainActivity or View activity?!

Comment: where is your View Activity man. You have to add this in Main Activity.

Comment: it gives me PointerNullException. and my MainActivity extends Activity  shouldnt i have another class to extend View to do the animation and import onDraw. as i mentioned im new at this please be patient with me  and i meant CloudView when i said my View activity

Comment: man change the name of the layout to which you want to inflate. Don't use the same name.